# @RabbitListener for the same queue in multiple classes

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I was wondering if it is possible in Spring AMQP to receive messages from the same queue in multiple classes depending on the payload type.

I am aware of using the @RabbitListener annotation in class and then putting @RabbitHandler on methods, but I would like to split complexity of message handling in multiple classes while keeping a single queue.

Version currently in use: Spring AMQP v2.0.3 along with RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it isn't possible. The way you would like it won't be a *queue* then.
That is really an architecture decision to design a single *listener* and distribute to its methods according the `payload` type.

As a workaround I can suggest you to delegate the logic from a single `@RabbitListener` class to those business services:

```java
    @RabbitListener(queues = "foo")
    public class MyListener {

        private final ServiceA serviceA;

        private final ServiceB serviceB;

        public MyListener(ServiceA serviceA, ServiceB serviceB) {
              this.serviceA = serviceA;
              this.serviceB = serviceB;
        }


        @RabbitHandler
        public void handleA(A a) {
             this.serviceA.handle(a);
        }

        @RabbitHandler
        public void handleB(B b) {
             this.serviceB.handle(b);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is what I was already doing, just needed to verify there is no other way.
I think the issue in Spring AMQP is that you cannot have multiple consumers on the same queue.

Comment: You can, but then they are going to be *competing consumers* and there won't be a way to control messages distribution for their payload type. You need to consume message, convert its `byte[]` into a desired type, and only after that your will be able to route the result to the appropriate method to process. But that is already out side of the AMQP protocol and that already will be an issue do not follow the protocol in the Spring AMQP. You can consider to use different queues for different payloads though and route them on the Broker level vial `routing key`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but it takes a little different approach:
You need lo listen to the generic Message Type, do some switching, and your own deserialisation. You can of course completly hide that code somewhere (baseclass, annotations...)

Example below can be extended to listen to whatever types extra.
The example above would be to filter on A and B DTO types.

```
void receive(ADTO dto)
{
    System.out.print(dto.url);
}

void receive(BDTO dto)
{
    System.out.print(dto.url);
}
@RabbitListener(queues = "your.queue.name")
public void listenMesssage(Message message) 
 {
    try 
    {
        String typeId = message.getMessageProperties().getHeaders().get("__TypeId__").toString();
        String contentType = message.getMessageProperties().getContentType();
        if (contentType != "application/json" || typeId == null || !typeId.contains(ADTO.class.toString()))
        {
            //TODO log warning
            System.out.print("type not supported by this service");
            return;
        }
        Object receivedObject = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter().fromMessage(message);

        if (receivedObject instanceof ADTO)
        {
            receive((ADTO)receivedObject);
            System.out.print("ADTO");
        }
        //else
```

Alternatively, you can also do the serialisation like this:

```
....
String typeId = message.getMessageProperties().getHeaders().get("__TypeId__").toString();
byte[] binMsg =  message.getBody();
String strMsg  = new String(binMsg, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
if (typeId.contains("ADTO"))
{
   receive(mapper.readValue(strMsg, ADTO.class ));
}
else
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I found out, if you have a high enough version of AQMP and Rabbit
(mine = spring-rabit 2.1.3, spring-starter-aqmp 2.1.2) you can do this polymorph:

```
@RabbitListener(id="multi", queues = "somequeuename")
public class SomeService 
{
    @RabbitHandler
    public void handleADTO(@Payload ADTO adto) {
         System.out.print(adto.url);
    }

    @RabbitHandler
    public void handleADTO2(@Payload ADTO2 adto) {
         System.out.print(adto.url);
    }
}
```

However, out of the box, this does not work. You need to configure another "bag of Beans":

```
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory myFactory(
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory =
            new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}

@Bean
RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    template.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
    return template;
}
```

Just put it in your app, or some other class.

See also

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/